# Anaphoric Macro symbols have a prefix from a different package, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm attempting to write my first anaphoric macro and am running into a problem. I am using sblc and slime.

When the anaphoric macro is expanded in another package its symbols are prefixed with the package it was defined in (i.e. they become `tjb-utilities::value` instead of just `value`. What is going on?

```
PE> (macroexpand-1 '(act-if-key :pcram (get-node) (print value)))
(IF (HAS-KEY? :PCRAM (GET-NODE))
    (LET ((TJB-UTILITIES::KEY :PCRAM)
          (TJB-UTILITIES::VALUE (GETHASH :PCRAM (GET-NODE))))
      (PRINT VALUE)))
```

This is the macro definition:

```
(defmacro act-if-key (key hashtable &body body)
  `(if (has-key? ,key ,hashtable) 
       (let ((key ,key) (value (gethash ,key ,hashtable)))
     ,@body)))
```

It does work correclty if I prefix the value:

```
(act-if-key :pcram (get-node) (print tjb-utilities::value))
; in: ACT-IF-KEY :PCRAM
;     (LET ((TJB-UTILITIES::KEY :PCRAM)
;           (TJB-UTILITIES::VALUE
;            (GETHASH :PCRAM (PHILOSOPHY-EXPERIENCE::GET-NODE))))
;       (PRINT TJB-UTILITIES::VALUE))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable TJB-UTILITIES::KEY is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

"hello" 
"hello"
```

The packages are defined as follows:

```
(defpackage #:tjb-utilities
  (:nicknames :tjb)
  (:use #:cl)
  (:export "HAS-KEY?" "KEY-VALUE-PAIRS" "ACT-IF-KEY" "TJB-MAKE-HASH-TABLE"))

(defpackage #:my-package
  (:nicknames :pe)
  (:use #:cl #:clsql #:tjb-utilities))
```

Update: Changing the key in the lambda list to key_in has no effect

```
(defmacro act-if-key (key_in hashtable &body body)
  `(if (has-key? ,key_in ,hashtable) 
       (let ((key ,key_in) (value (gethash ,key_in,hashtable)))
     ,@body)))
```

Comment: The best way to learn is to find out how it's done in real-life libraries like [anaphora](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/anaphora/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (in-package #:tjb)
#<PACKAGE "TJB-UTILITIES">
TJB> (defmacro act-if-key (key hashtable &body body)
       (let ((value (intern "VALUE")))
         `(if (has-key? ,key ,hashtable) 
              (let ((key ,key) (,value (gethash ,key ,hashtable)))
                ,@body))))
ACT-IF-KEY
TJB> (macroexpand-1 '(tjb:act-if-key :pcram (get-node) (print value)))
(IF (HAS-KEY? :PCRAM (GET-NODE))
    (LET ((KEY :PCRAM) (VALUE (GETHASH :PCRAM (GET-NODE))))
      (PRINT VALUE)))
T
TJB> (in-package #:cl-user)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(tjb:act-if-key :pcram (get-node) (print value)))
(IF (TJB-UTILITIES::HAS-KEY? :PCRAM (GET-NODE))
    (LET ((TJB-UTILITIES::KEY :PCRAM) (VALUE (GETHASH :PCRAM (GET-NODE))))
      (PRINT VALUE)))
T
CL-USER>
```

Not sure if I copied all that you needed, and I'm a tad blur on how did you intend to use the "key", so I did it only for the `value` in the way it will be created in the package, where the macro is used. You'd figure it for yourself whether you need the same for the `key` or not.

The above bind the symbol `value` in the current package to whatever `gethash` will return. In your original version you have `key` supplied by the user of the macro, so I decided you didn't want a symbol `key` inside the macro, just it's value.

But wait a bit, perhaps there will be a better answer, maybe you can just `make-symbol` it instead of interning and then bind it somehow. I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, my solution in this case was more of a learning excercise, not sure if I will use this anywhere

Comment: In this case, `INTERN` is probably the right thing. If you use `MAKE-SYMBOL`, you're effectively using an uninterned symbol, so the `value` within the macro-expansion is not the `value` passed in by the macro-user. That way lies sadness and horrible hours of debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You could just export 'key and 'value symbols. That's how [Anaphora](http://common-lisp.net/project/anaphora/) does it:

```
(defpackage :anaphora
7     (:use :cl)
8     (:export
9      #:it
10     #:alet
11     #:slet
12     #:aif
13     #:aand
14     #:sor
15     #:awhen
16     #:aprog1
17     #:acase
18     #:aecase
...etc.
```

Note the 'it export.

The point of an anaphoric macro is to intentionally capture certain symbols in the body of the macro that have not been explicitly defined by the caller of the macro (I understand that this is an extreme stance on the definition). So, it is a requirement for anyone using an anaphoric macro to know what symbols are being introduced into the environment (body) of that macro. Which means that they should not be surprised when those symbol names are added to the environment. So I see no problem with exporting the anaphora.